# check box design issue after migrating my native script application

Tags: angular, checkbox, migration, nativescript

I'm using "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^2.0.4", package for designing the check box in my application.
After migrating, the check box design not matching properly.
Facing alignment issue in checkbox.

How to fix this design issue?

[image: Click here to see error image]